# Functions with pointers in exercise 16 learn c the hard way

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have a question about ex 16 of [learn C the hard way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex16.html).

There is a function definition at the beginning of the code:

```
struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
};

struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
{
    struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(who != NULL);

    who->name = strdup(name);
    who->age = age;
    who->height = height;
    who->weight = weight;

    return who;
}
```

What is the reason that the function is written with a pointer? *Person_create?
I really have problems understanding the whole concept of pointers and when you should use them. Can anybody help me?

Comment: "I really have problems understanding the whole concept of pointers and when you should use them" — closing as too broad.

Comment: Google "C pointers" and you will get a lot of different explanations about what pointers are and why you would use them. First results I get are a tutorial on c pointers and what they are (http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm), Pointers in C  (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm) and lots more that will be able to help.

Comment: Take a look at [this SO question and the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap/80113#80113). It might help.

Comment: It's written with a pointer because this is the only way you can create an object within a function without having that object cease to exist when that function ends. Programming would be fantastically more difficult if you couldn't do this. The memory you allocate with `malloc()` (unlike the pointer variable `who`, for instance) survives the end of that function, but because none of the *names* declared in that function do, the address of that memory becomes the only way you have to subsequently refer to it, and that's what the function returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core reason for returning a pointer from `Person_create` is that it is returning memory that has been dynamically allocated with `malloc`.  The only way you can track dynamic memory in C is through a pointer value.

> I really have problems understanding the whole concept of pointers and when you should use them.

**What are pointers?**

Conceptually, pointers are simple beasties; any expression that evaluates to the location of an object in memory is a pointer.  Given the declaration

```
int x;
```

then the *expression* `&x` is a pointer - it evaluates to the address of the variable `x`.  You can store pointer values in variables of pointer type:

```
int *p = &x;
```

Now `p` is also a pointer expression, since it will evaluate to the address of `x`.

Pointer declaration syntax can be a little confusing.  Declarations in C are based on the types of "expressions", not objects.  Given a pointer to an integer named `p`, you access the integer value by *deferencing* `p` with the unary `*` operator:

```
q = *p;
```

The type of the *expression* `*p` is `int`, so it follows that the declaration of `p` is

```
int *p;
```

You could write it as `int* p`, but it will be parsed as `int (*p)`; the `*` is always bound to the declarator, not the type specifier.

Pointer expressions have type information associated with them; a pointer to `int` is a different type from a pointer to `double`, which is a different type from a pointer to `char`, etc.  This matters for pointer arithmetic; `p + 1` will give a different result if `p` is a `char *` or an `int *`, because it gives you the address of the next instance of the pointed-to type.

**When do I use them?**

C *requires* you to use pointers in two cases.  The first is when you are tracking dynamically allocated memory, as above.  The second is when you want a function to write to its parameters, and have those changes reflected in the caller. Think about a library function like `scanf`:

```
int x;
...
scanf( "%d", &x );
```

You want `scanf` to write something to `x`, so you must pass a *pointer* to `x`.

The one monkey wrench in this is array expressions; under most circumstances, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  That's why you *don't* use the `&` operator when calling `scanf` on an array of `char`:

```
char buf[N];
scanf( "%s", buf );
```

Under this circumstance, the expression `buf` is converted to a pointer type automatically, and using `&` in this instance would be a mistake.

Pointers have a number of other uses, though; you'll typically see them used to iterate through an array, or to build dynamic data structures, or to identify substrings in a larger string, stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! 
I just rewrote the code without pointers, and if I understand correctly the main difference is now that if I create a new struc it is on the stack instead of on the heap. Furthermore, I can not write something to a structure I created. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

That code is poorly formatted. The star `*` in front of `Person_create` actually applies to the return type. So `Person_create()` returns a `struct Person*`.

You can further determine this by checking that the variable returned (`who`) is of type `struct Person*`. Note that since memory is dynamically created by `Person_create()` through the use of `malloc()`, you must delete that memory using `free()` when you are done with it.

Comment: There are (at least) two camps on the formatting issue.  One prefers declarations like `int* p` (since the type of `p` is `int*`), while other likes  `int *p;` (since the type of `*p` is `int`) and there are good arguments for each.  It's not "poor formatting".

Answer (score 0):

All that it is saying is it will return a pointer to `struct Person` type. Following is the breakdown.

- `Person_create` : function name
- `struct Person *` : return type. This is pointer to `struct Person`.
- `(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)` : function arguments

One reason for functions to return pointers to `struct`s (as in this case) is to avoid copying whole `struct`s which would be slow and resource inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that a pointer is typically 4 or 8 bytes so it is faster to pass around pointers to a person struct then to copy all the data in it.